# How to set System Wide Environment Variable in Cloud Config File on Digital Ocean

Tags: environment-variables, digital-ocean

I am pretty new to setting up remote servers, but I was playing around today and was hoping that I could leverage a [Cloud Config](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-cloud-config-for-your-initial-server-setup) file upon setup in order to set a few environment variables as the server spins up.

How can I set my environment variables programmatically when spinning up a machine on Digital Ocean? The key is that I want to automate the setup and avoid interactively defining these variables.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

This is what I did with for ubuntu

```
write_files:
- path: /etc/environment
  content: |
    FOO="BAR"
  append: true
```

Answer (score 5):

There's a couple ways to do this, although [Cloud Init](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) doesn't support a built-in resource type for environment variables.

1. Depending on your OS, use a `write-files` section to output the env vars you want to the appropriate file. For CoreOS, you'd do something like:

   ```
   write_files:
       - path: "/etc/profile.env"
         append: true
         content: |
           export MY_VAR="foo"
   ```

For Ubuntu, use `/etc/environment`, or a user's profile, etc.

2. Another way to do it would be to leverage Cloud Init's support for Chef, and use that tool to [set the variables](https://docs.chef.io/resource_env.html) when the profile is applied.

Comment: not recommended, this will overwrite the environment variable file. use `append: true` to prevent this

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the environment variable to be permanent, or just for the execution of a single command/script?
If it's for a single command, you can do that:

```
FOO=${BAR} | sh ./your_script.sh
```

Comment: this just doesnt work this does though

# BAR="test"
# FOO=${BAR} | sh -c 'echo $FOO'

# FOO=${BAR} sh -c 'echo $FOO'
test
#